# My text writes over itself when it's long enough

Tags: css

I don't really know how to explain the problem. I usually find the answer to my problems on the site but I think I don't know how to define the question correctly.

My text keeps falling over itself. I want a large text for my page titles and I've tried using different length units for my text (e.g., px, %, em) but the problem still persists.

[image]

Comment: Look into the "overflow" css property.

Comment: Post the CSS for that text. I think your `line-height` got set really small.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your line hight is way too small for the text size you're using.

Play around with the `line-height` CSS property to get it spaced out the way you want.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_line-height.asp

Answer (score 0):

I didn't define line-height, silly me.

The overflow wasn't working. I tried it.

Thanks a lot guys.

Comment: I am more of a stalker and can't give upvotes :( sorry